# multithreading using python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

Trying to understand the following results when using multithreading with python. The following code prints A and B to the console in random sequence, which is what I would like to achieve. But the second piece of code only prints "A" to the console, and never proceeds past t1.start(). Why is this? What do I need to do the the second section of code to make it behave like the first?

Thanks in advance, this is my first post.

This is the behavior I want :

```
from threading import Thread
def runA():
    while True:
        print ('A\n')

def runB():
    while True:
        print ('B\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
     t1 = Thread(target = runA())
     t2 = Thread(target = runB())
     t1.setDaemon(True)
     t2.setDaemon(True)
     t1.start()
     t2.start()
     while True:
         pass
```

I want the behavior produced from the above code but using classes like in the example below. The code below never executes t2.start(). Why is this?

```
from threading import Thread
class test():
     def runA(self):
         while True:
             print ('A\n')

     def runB(self):
         while True:
             print ('B\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
     testingNow=test()
     t1 = Thread(target = testingNow.runA())
     t2 = Thread(target = testingNow.runB())
     t1.setDaemon(True)
     t2.setDaemon(True)
     t1.start()
     t2.start()
     while True:
         pass
```

Comment: You sure the first code snippet actually does what you want? I think you introduced the same bug from the second snippet when you retyped your code into the question box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the `()` in `testingNow.runA()` and `testingNow.runB()`.

Comment: That's it! I'm new to python, didn't realize that made a difference! Thanks!